# Algorithm used in d3 block

Tags: algorithm, d3.js

Here is this block :

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/a76006c5bc2a95695c6f

Could somebody explain which algorithm is used and how it works ? I know how  d3.js works, so i do not need an explanation of the d3 stuff, but i had like to understand how the algorithm works in this viz

Many thanks,

Comment: Which algorithm in particular? Picking the closest linesegment, or calculating the linesegments?

Comment: From what i see, it seems there is a sort of quadtree that is built from the various segment. Then this quadtree is searched when the mouse moves, when the right quadrant is found, the segment contained in it is highlighted. I had like to have more details on these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple Divide-et-Impera algorithm. You analyze the current function and see if it is close enough (what is meand by **close enough** is yet another matter though) to a straight line that goes from the left-side value (the leftmost value in the section you are currently considering) to the right-side value (the rightmost value in the section you are currently considering) of the function itself. If the value is close enough then the algorithm stops (at least for the current area), otherwise you split the area in two and execute the algorithm in both sides.